# Select the data and generate the SELECT for each day from date to date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this `SELECT` statement in SQL Server:

```
select testname as 'Test', 
       tests_morning , 
       tests_evening ,
       Date
from  labtests_hajj 
left join departments_statistics on departments_statistics.test_id = labtests_hajj.testid 
inner join departments on labtests_hajj.dept_id = departments.dept_id
```

The output now like this:

```
Test      tests_morning         tests_evening Date 
CBC       null                  null          null 
CALCIUM   null                  null          null   
SODIUMN   null                  null          null
```

How can I get the output as script and add the date also depends on date range for example I need the output for 3 days to be like this :

```
Test      tests_morning      tests_evening   Date 
CBC       null                  null     01/06/2023 
CALCIUM   null                  null     01/06/2023  
SODIUMN   null                  null     01/06/2023

CBC       null                  null     02/06/2023 
CALCIUM   null                  null     02/06/2023  
SODIUMN   null                  null     02/06/2023     
                                           
CBC       null                  null     03/06/2023 
CALCIUM   null                  null     03/06/2023  
SODIUMN   null                  null     03/06/2023
```

How can I do the select and put 2 dates and show the output like thie?

Comment: `JOIN` to your calendar table.

Comment: @ThomA which calendar table how to do it ?

Comment: *Your* calendar table. You *do* have a calendar table, right? If not, why not? Take the time and invest in creating one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are have two ways

1. use DimDate or calendar table
2. you create a date table yourself with CTE

With DimDate

```
declare @StartData date='2023-02-01'
declare @EndData date='2023-02-06'
;with _t as 
(
    select testname as 'Test', 
           tests_morning , 
           tests_evening ,
           Date
    from  labtests_hajj 
    left join departments_statistics 
                     on departments_statistics.test_id = labtests_hajj.testid 
    inner join departments on labtests_hajj.dept_id = departments.dept_id

)
select 
             a.Test
            ,a.tests_morning
            ,a.tests_evening
            ,s.Date_ as  Date
from _t 
cross apply (select * from DimDate where date_ between  @StartData and @EndData )s
```

If your date range is consecutive, you can create the desired data by setting the start and end dates with CTE.

```
declare @StartData date='2023-02-01'
declare @EndData date='2023-02-06'
;WITH List
as
(
    SELECT @StartData as Date_
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Date_) as 'MonthStart'
    FROM List
    where Date_<= @EndData
),
_t as 
(
    select testname as 'Test', 
           tests_morning , 
           tests_evening ,
           Date
    from  labtests_hajj 
    left join departments_statistics on departments_statistics.test_id = labtests_hajj.testid 
    inner join departments on labtests_hajj.dept_id = departments.dept_id
)
select 
              a.Test
            ,a.tests_morning
            ,a.tests_evening
            ,s.Date_ as  Date
from _t  a
cross apply (select * from List)s
```

Comment: As a note, for a *small* number of dates, the performance difference between an rCTE and Tally or (well indexed) Calendar Table is going to be negliable. For a large range, however, then an rCTE will be (much) less performant. Not to mention that the `MAXRECURSION` `OPTION` will need to be specified if more than 100 days are required (with the rCTE solution).

Comment: thank you so much its working I used first example but just add a its missing (from _t  a)  I created DimDate table and inserted range one month :)

Comment: last question please after run the SELECT how can I INSERT the output into the table departments_statistics ?

Comment: You can write this query" insert into your table " after cte